Why are the threshold coefficients of my cumulative link mixed model seemingly very large?
I'm fitting a cumulative link mixed model with the ordinal package. The data is repeated measures (survey taken at three time points). The model converges without issue and the estimates look reasonable to me but the threshold co-efficients seem very inflated and I'm curious to know potential reasons why and the consequences (i.e., is this model likely to still be informative).
library(ordinal)

data(q1_data)

head(q1_data)

     id day   response sex     glp weight1 weight2
  <dbl> <fct> <ord>    <chr> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1 day7  5        m     100.    -1.40   -1.45
2     1 day2  4        m     100.    -1.40   -1.45
3     1 day0  3        m     100.    -1.40   -1.45
4     2 day7  5        f      97.8   -1.10   -1.55
5     2 day2  5        f      97.8   -1.10   -1.55
6     2 day0  6        f      97.8   -1.10   -1.55 

Running the model:
q1_clmm <- clmm(response ~ day + weight1 * weight2 + glp + 
                           (1 | id),
                     data = q1_data,
                     link = "logit",
                     nAGQ = 5)
summary(q1_clmm)

Not sure how much I should be pasting but to give the full context:
Cumulative Link Mixed Model fitted with the adaptive Gauss-Hermite 
 quadrature approximation with 5 quadrature points 

formula: response ~ day + weight1 * weight2 + glp + (1 | id)
data:    q1_data

 link  threshold nobs logLik  AIC    niter     max.grad cond.H 
 logit flexible  159  -219.91 465.82 793(3020) 4.28e-04 6.3e+06

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 id     (Intercept) 1.194    1.093   
Number of groups:  id 53 

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
dayday2         -0.59368    0.37344  -1.590  0.11189   
dayday7         -0.07920    0.38261  -0.207  0.83602   
weight1         -1.41946    0.46628  -3.044  0.00233 **
weight2          0.39884    0.16354   2.439  0.01473 * 
glp              0.06027    0.02302   2.618  0.00884 **
weight1:weight2 -0.50004    0.17551  -2.849  0.00438 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Threshold coefficients:
    Estimate Std. Error z value
0|1  -0.2991     2.4189  -0.124
1|2   0.8646     2.2783   0.379
2|3   2.2481     2.2304   1.008
3|4   3.4143     2.2253   1.534
4|5   5.1067     2.2478   2.272
5|6   7.2607     2.3074   3.147

My concern is that the threshold estimates and SEs are very high. The increasingly high values are also in the opposite direction I would have expected, as the data is a bit sparse around 1-3 with higher frequency of responses around 4-6. My understanding is that these are in logodds and the exponential results in an OR of 1423 and an upper bound OR of 131018 for the 5|6 cutoff.
I presume this is an issue? Does this mean the model is having a difficult time accurately modelling the data? Has something gone wrong in my modelling process? Potential for overfitting (performance metrics seem reasonable e.g., R2 cond is 0.4, RMSE = 4.34 and these values are not altered substantially by further simplification of the model)?
Please let me know if other information is required and I'll update this OP.

This may be more appropriate for stats stackexchange because it is not really about the software implementation, really it's more about the stat model. However I don't see anything wrong per se with the high threshold coefficient. It is an intercept so the 5/6 cutoff is the modeled cumulative probability of 5 or less, if all covariates are 0. That may be reasonable for your data.

One thing you should check, though, is whether the proportional odds assumption is met. You can relax that assumption with the clmm2() function. Also see here https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/dae/ordinal-logistic-regression/ for info on how to qualitatively check the assumption

Thanks both – and to the mods who migrated the Q to cross-validated.
@qdread many thanks for the response. I managed to get the visualisation working and it looks like the PO assumption is likely violated for the lower thresholds. I ran an identically structured clmm2 model which runs into issues as the model "appears to be rank-deficient, so dropping some coefs". It still converges and I get interpretable estimates, the size and direction of which resemble the original clmm model. AIC/BIC are marginally higher for clmm2. Any further advice here is appreciated.

I'm not an expert on ordinal regression, but I suspect that the threshold values have to do with having glp values that are far from 0.
With the way that the ordinal package sets up the model, the thresholds are the cutoffs in the linear predictor (logit linked to probability) that distinguish ordinal classes when the predictor values are all at 0 or reference levels. See Equation 10 of the package vignette.
It looks like you might have centered/scaled your weight1 and weight2 values, so values for them and their interaction might typically be near 0. The glp values, in contrast, seem to be well above 0. The thresholds thus might be for a glp value far from a typical value. Try centering glp values about their mean and see what happens to the thresholds.
You'll also notice that the example in Section 4.1 of the vignette, with only 5 outcome classes, has a range of 6.3 logit units in thresholds, while you have a range of about 7.6 units for 7 outcome classes. That doesn't seem too different, suggesting that there isn't a substantial problem with their point estimates. The standard errors presumably represent the imperfect discrimination provided by your model.
Frank Harrell has some valuable online resources for ordinal regression. These models can be robust against violations of the proportional odds assumption. The ordinal package also allows for category-specific coefficients if you deem them necessary. See Section 4.2 of the vignette.

Thank you for the response. I centered the glp variable and it resulted in the same threshold estimates. I agree with your assessment that the threshold estimates themselves aren't a substantial problem. The proportional odds assumption looked to be violated. Stuck with the PO model and emphasised the estimates as being an average odds ratio in the reporting, which was fine for the research question.
